# Docker using 25-35% CPU with NO running container/apps - how to really idle?

Tags: macos, docker, macos-catalina, docker-desktop

- Why?
- Is there any possibility/setting of having the com.docker.hyperkit really just idling when there's no container/app active/running??

Docker Desktop for Mac (newest version): +already started & "idling" with nothing running whatsoever (which Docker UI confirms me).

Machine: 16" MBP (enough RAM, SSD space left, besides virtually no CPU load)

25-35% just seems too much for running/idling a basically fancy headless background app

**EDIT**:

No kubernetes context

docker info:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.3.4)

Server:
 Containers: 3
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 11
 Server Version: 19.03.13
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.39-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 6
 Total Memory: 1.941GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: HEUF:LROW:RJOR:N2JR:FKJ3:A4TX:URMS:XVCX:WNCH:RSY6:BYFG:P57O
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3129
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

Comment: Please show `docker info`, and let us know if kubernetes is enabled.

Comment: `docker ps -a` would also be useful output, as it will show us the status of all containers that aren't destroyed yet (because destroying a container is different from stopping one.

Comment: Also, my guess, is that since docker is running a Linux virtual machine, (because MacOS doesn't support containerization and runs a different kernel altogether), the extra cpu is being burned by just keeping up the virtual machine. Looks like you have 3 stopped containers, and so docker will keep the vm around in case you want to start those up again. Stopping those containers might help, but outright restarting the docker-desktop service should definitely do the trick.

Comment: @SteveGoob … no it doesn't, after a few secs it's back up to the cpu usage